# Markeitng Cloud SSJS Describe Method

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssjs

I would like to know the properties I can send in Requests for object, with SSJS. I'm think I may achieve this with the [Describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_describe.htm?search_text=describe) Method, because in docs of [RetrieveRequest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieverequest.htm), there is the `Properties` attribute (option) to send in the request. In it Description says:

> [...] You can retrieve allowed properties using the Describe method.

How can I use this `Describe` method in SSJS?

Comment: The example you link to (WSproxy) is actually SSJS

Comment: Yeah I am confused. It seems like you answered your own question via the linked docs. Can you clarify what you are asking?

Comment: I'm sorry, I messed up the question, I was supposed to ask with the SSJS Core libary or Plataform Function.